# HTTPURLConnetion to hit a service

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am little confused with the below code or behavior of HttpURLConnection class. I have the below code which hits the URL (rest service in .net) and gets the response from it. When I run the code I am getting the response in both Windows and Unix environment. I have access to this URL.

When I provided the same code to someone who don't have access to the URL, it throws `401 Unauthorized` error. But in below code I didn't pass my credentials, how does it automatically validates my credentials ? Is it working for me because HttpURLConnection sets Windows authentication in background in request ?

```
    URL url = new URL(URL);         
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");             
    connection.setUseCaches(false); 
    connection.setDoOutput(true); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 
    String inputLine; 
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        response.append(inputLine); 
    } 
    in.close(); 
    System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Unlikely. Could there be a proxy between the client and the server in one case and not the other?

Comment: Or could the security policy be based on IP addresses?

Comment: might be as well as a restriction on the server side. Are you in the same network? Perhaps authentication is only enforced for unknown hosts?

Comment: If I ran this code from home, I would most likely get the server responses, whereas if I ran it from my work place, the proxy would ask for an authentication.

Comment: @Maurice Perry - there is no such ip filter implemented.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch - Person who got 401 and myself are in same network.

Comment: @Wave I'd suggest you use TCPMon to see what really is and is not sent. You may still ask the service provider to help you to resolve ..